# No way to convert this string to raw format for parsing

Tags: python

I am writing a program to find the latency of the following IP: '141.101.115.212' (A game server)

To find the latency I use the following commands:

```
x = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "141.101.115.212"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
x = str(x.communicate()[0])
```

If I print x, I find it contains the following output:

```
...Minimum = 46ms, Maximum = 54ms, Average = 48ms\r\n'
```

So I parse the output to obtain `48ms` with the following code:

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "141.101.115.212"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
x = str(x.communicate()[0])
lhs, rhs = x.split("Average = ")
lhs, rhs = rhs.split("\\")
print(lhs)
```

But I receive the following error because `rhs` is not a raw string.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michael/PycharmProjects/untitled/expiriment.py", line 6, in <module>
    lhs, rhs = rhs.split("\\")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How do I convert the string `rhs` to a raw string?

**edit:**

As you can see by printing `rhs`, the code works after the first split, but not the second.

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "141.101.115.212"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
x = str(x.communicate()[0])
print(x)
lhs, rhs = x.split("Average = ")
print(rhs)
lhs, rhs = rhs.split("\\")
print (lhs)
```

**edit:**

I do infact need to cast communicate as a string.

**edit:**

The only way to split a string at a back slash with Python is to convert the string to raw e.g.

```
string = r"asdasd\asdasd"
lhs, rhs = string.split("\\")
print(rhs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with raw strings. It looks like your value is being split in to 3 elements not 2.

Comment: `x.communicate()[0]` is already a string

Comment: It won't split at the back slash, so I used two thinking it would work as an escape sequence. It only works that way when the string is raw. For example, this works `string = r"asdasd\asdasd" /
lhs, rhs = string.split("\\") /
print(rhs)`

Comment: use `print(x.rstrip().rsplit("= ",1)[-1])`

Comment: That leaves me with `66ms\r\n'`. I still need to get rid of the stuff to the right including the backslash.

Comment: not when you print it is won't, that is a return and newline char `x.replace("\\r\\n","").rsplit("= ",1)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean, these were the last two lines of my code: `x = str(x.communicate()[0]) / print(x.rstrip().rsplit("= ", 1)[-1])`

Comment: just use replace, as I said earlier you don't need to cast communicate as a string

Comment: That's what I thought, but it turns out communicate is not a string, even if it prints out as one. Odd as that sounds... this code is not working... `import subprocess
x = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "141.101.115.212"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) / print(x.rstrip().rsplit("= ", 1)[-1])`

Comment: so you are saying the following does not work, `x = x.communicate()[0].splitlines()`?  It is most certainly a string

Comment: Maybe I'm not using your method correctly, but I get the error `'Popen' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`

Comment: that is because you are using `x` twice, do `print(x.communicate()[0].rstrip().rsplit("= ", 1)[-1])`, you are not recasting x to `communicate()[0] ` before calling the string methods on x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there are two back slashes in the string, and you need the specify to split at the first string.

the problem

```
lhs, rhs = rhs.split("\\")
```

the solution

```
lhs, rhs = rhs.split("\\", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you try to assign the result to exactly two variables, but there are more than that.

Your string most certainly contains more than one backslash

You could get all of them with

```
res = rhs.split("\\")
```

Then search res for what you need

Edit

By your comments, rhs is `57ms\r\n` before the split. This will cause split to return 3 values, 57ms, r, n. lhs could get 57ms, rhs will get r, but n is not handled so python panics and shows that error.

I think that what you really want to do is to remove the line break. This should sanitize to 57ms

```
res = rhs.replace('\r\n','')
```

Comment: this works and is my model, and you can see the string is a raw string and the double back slashes work.... `string = r"asdasd\asdasd"  / 
lhs, rhs = string.split("\\")  /  
print(rhs)`

Comment: Can you print rhs before the split?

Comment: After the first split, yes

Comment: I wanted to validate the value being splitted before it happens

Comment: The value is `57ms\r\n'`

Comment: So you do have multiple backslashes in that string. Maybe what you really need is res = rhs.replace(r'\r\n', '')